# How to open my plugin contents in a new tab in the Mattermost desktop app

Tags: plugins, jsx, electron-forge, mattermost

I’m developing a plugin for Mattermsot which shows an iframe and the contents I need inside the iframe, Currently, I have managed to register this as a product and now it shows in the product switcher,
[image]

When I click the Iframe button it opens the Iframe in the same window as the channels, What I need is open it from a new tab similar to boards and playbooks in the Mattermost desktop app, in the web browser it can be as it is now.

Thank you for your support.

Here is my plugin code

```
import React from 'react';


let iframeURL = "https://codepen.io/rdesigncode/details/zYPzaqb"
const customRoute = '/myplugin';


class myplugin{
  

    initialize(registry, store) {

      

      const IframeComponent = () => {
        return (
          <iframe src={iframeURL} height="100%" width="100%" title="myplugin"></iframe> 
        );
      };


    registry.registerProduct(
      customRoute,
      'kanban',
      "IFrame",
      customRoute,
      IframeComponent,
      'headerCentreComponent',
      'headerRightComponent',
      true,
      true,
      true
    );

        }
      }
window.registerPlugin('myplugin', new myplugin());
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click the `Iframe` button, it opens the Iframe in the same window as the channels. You would like to open it from a new tab similar to `boards and playbooks` in the `Mattermost desktop app`. Currently this isn't *not* supported by `Mattermost desktop app.`
one alternative could be to open the contents of your plugin in a new window instead of a new tab, using `JavaScript`  (  open a new window with the desired URL when the user clicks on the `Iframe` button ) . See below

```
const openInNewWindow = () => {
    window.open(iframeURL, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
}
```

call this function when the user clicks on the `Iframe` button to open the contents of your `plugin` in a new window.

Comment: Thank you, I have already gone through this kind of a solution and it's not good with my application. After a lot of hours, I understand it's not possible with plugins, I'm looking to create my own MM desktop version now. Thanks again

Comment: well u bountied the Q. wait for a better A & see who'd get ....g luck with 

Comment: I don't think anyone else will even try , Thank you again btw

Comment: well now that ue bounty meter is on.. it should attract  passerbys who think they can dabble around a bit. If nothing u won't get your bounty back ❗ so might as well give it way ❗